# Laravel Cashier: Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException No such customer: cus_H0zcimyzC93Bay

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, e-commerce, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to subscribe an authenticated user to a plan with Laravel Cashier. The post request to the Stripe dashboard is marked as a '200 success'.

However, Laravel will throw this exception: Laravel Cashier: Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException No such customer: cus_H0zcimyzC93Bay

I'm not entirely sure what this means. The user I'm trying to subscribe has this stripe_id: cus_H0zcimyzC93Bay. So why am I being told there's no such customer with that ID?

I've had a look at this post here: [Laravel Cashier + Stripe: No Such Customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811509/laravel-cashier-stripe-no-such-customer) and it didn't help me. Although I get the same exception I don't think our solutions are the same.

The solution in that post is to make the relevant database case-insensitive. I think my database is already case-insensitive as I've queried my database for the stripe_id with Tinker and it returns the stripe_id as is: cus_H0zcimyzC93Bay.

I also don't know how to make my database case-insensitive. Besides, I don't think that's the issue.

Here's my code that causes the error:

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->paymentMethod;
        $plan = $request->planId;

        // 'create' method will automatically store customers payment method
        $user->newSubscription('subscription', $request->plan)->create($paymentMethod, [
            'email' => $user->email
        ]); 

        redirect()
        ->route('confirmation')
        ->with('subscriptionSuccessMessage', 'You have successfully subscribed. See you around!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the Customer is in a different Stripe Account than the Account that this code is currently trying to make use of, either as a result of testing in a different account, or as a result of Connect.